# Rest API - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, ubuntu, rest, glassfish, http-status-code-500

Веб-сервис был разработан в среде IntelliJ IDEA на win7. Использовался сервер GlassFish 4.1.1 c "апгрейдом" известных проблем. Сервис работал как надо. При переносе сервиса на Ubuntu возникла проблема.Переносил war-файл и деплоил его на Ubuntu на сервер GlassFish 5.0. Запрос PUT перестал работать. Сервер выдает ошибку 500, а именно:

> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error
>   deserializing object from entity stream. root cause
>
> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from
>   entity stream. root cause
>
> javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error deserialize JSON value into
>   type: class java.util.UUID. note The full stack traces of the
>   exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server
>   Open Source Edition 5.0 logs.

Сам лог:

> [2018-04-15T12:19:16.785-0700] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] []
>   [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=86
>   _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1523819956785] [levelValue: 900] [[   StandardWrapperValve[MyApp]: Servlet.service()
>   for servlet MyApp threw exception javax.json.bind.JsonbException:
>   Error deserialize JSON value into type: class java.util.UUID.

Что-то ему не нравится объект UUID, но при этом на win7 всё работает. Что не так?

P.S. При необходимости добавлю код, потребуется.

Comment: `The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0 logs.` Найдите полную трассировку стека в логах Glassfish.

Comment: Ну в логах о том же самом и пишется. Добавил лог в вопрос. Проблема то в том, почему на одной ОС всё идёт без проблем, а на другой -из 4х запросов работает только 3?

Comment: на бубунте наверное open java, на в виндовсе oracle? если что ставьте oracle java и вместо glassfish попробуйте payara

Comment: @Sergey всё так, стоит open java. Спасибо за совет, попробую. Но, в чём же тогда причина? Что не так с _опенджавой_ и _глассфишем_ на убунте?

Comment: @ШураБалаганов open не работает не только лишь с glassfish-ем. у меня вот в дебияне то ли с wildfly-ем не пошло, то ли с netbeans-ом, не припомню. поставил oracle и проблема ушла.

Comment: @Sergey современный Oracle JDK - это просто прекомпилированная версия Open JDK с поддержкой. На уровне кода они идентичны.

Comment: @ШураБалаганов версии Java и Glassfish на сервере и вашем компьютере одинаковые? Зависимости все удовлетворяются при разворачивании проекта?

Comment: @Sergey Glassfish на win7 версии 4.1.1, а на убунте 5.0. Джава на win7 1.8.0_74, а на убунте openjdk 1.8.0_162

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev пофиг что там рассказывают какая open  хорошая и лучше oracle. я верю своим глазам и ушам. а вижу, что open не работает, а oracle работает. разбирать кто там из чего компилирует... зачем мне это? просто использую то, что работает

Comment: @ШураБалаганов попробуйте использовать 5.0 на своём компе. Можно даже с OpenJDK.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev сейчас буду пробовать разные варианты. Методом тыка надеюсь придти к нужному знаменателю) После напишу о результате

Comment: @Sergey поставил oracle java 8 и glassfish 5. не работает.

Comment: @ШураБалаганов значит дело в версии Glassfish. Пятая версия от четвёртой отличается версией EE. А восьмая EE от седьмой, в частности, использованием JSON Binding API.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev так какой ещё сервер можно попробовать? Payara кстати не пошёл

Comment: Все новые серверы используют JSON-B. Либо используйте старые сервера, либо придётся разобраться с сериализацией UUID в JSON-B.